# What is the simple approach for serverside rendering a react component in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5

1. I have created a separate react app using create-react-app. Developed some simple components like
2. npm run build
3. I copied everything from build folder and put it inside rails public folder
4. Inside one rails view erb file I just tried `<HelloWorld />`, but seems it's not working. It does not render the component.

(Note: I know react-rails and react-on-rails few gems are there, but I just want to understand why the above approach is not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<HelloWorld />`in a React app is actually JSX - that is Babel is - in the background - translating that markup into a Javascript function that creates an instance of the HelloWorld React component (in the context of a render method).

So, despite looking like HTML, it isn't really.  And copying it into an erb file that expects valid HTML (outside the delimiters `<%= %>` etc that indicate Ruby code) means that Rails doesn't render anything.

If you want to render a React component in a Rails view in a vanilla Rails app, you'd have to do it with Javascript.

Edit: I've somehow only just noticed the mention of "serverside rendering" in your question.  That requires a Javascript runtime on the server and the React code running in that context, as part of the rendering process.  There's nothing in a vanilla Rails app that will do that for you.

Comment: Ohh my mistake. Now I understood.